# Append value to column in gspread

Tags: python, gspread

I'm using Python 3 and I'm trying to append a string value to the last column without data, just like append_row does with rows.

As far as I know, add_cols adds columns at the end of the worksheet and col_count counts all columns, even if they don't have a value in it

Thanks

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. I cannot understand about `append a string value to the last column without data, just like append_row does with rows.`. Can I ask you about the detail of it? If you can do, could you please provide the sample Spreadsheet including the input and output you expect? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Sure. [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YGn9N.png) I would like to add "Category3" at D1 automatically. And keep adding more as the fields get populated

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. From your information, I proposed a sample script. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the direction you want, I apologize.

Comment: I noticed your answer just now. Thank you for your answer. I could understand that my answer was not useful for your situation.  I don't want to confuse other users. So I have to delete my answer. I couldn't image your script from your question. This is due to my poor skill. I deeply apologize for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't want to mess with lower-level calls since I'm not really a programmer. However your way seems a lot like the one I used. Just for clarification, I needed the header appended only.

I ended up getting the count of cells in the row like this:

```
firstRow = len(sheet.row_values(1))
```

And updating the next cell using that number

```
projCol = firstRow+1
sheet.update_cell(1, projCol, projName)
```